# Displaying custom caption for embed media in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to display custom caption for embed media (an youtube video).

`[caption title="hello"][embed src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1W8I8uoVPo"][/caption]`

but when I try to save the post it just strips the caption shortcode.

Am I doing something wrong?